# Cannot Convert the series to <class 'int'>?

Tags: python

I'm trying to change my dataset into an int, but this error keeps popping up:

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 93, in wrapper
  "{0}".format(str(converter)))

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

right now I have

```
dat = pd.read_csv('data.csv',names = ['date','x','y']
date = dat['date']
x = dat['x']
y = dat['y']
difdat = date[3]- date[2]
print (difdat)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the columns are date,x, and y! Wow, sorry I forgot to post date =dat['date']
x = dat['x']  y =dat['y']

Comment: then i difat =date[3]-date[2]

Comment: I want to subtract the value in the 4th row from the date section with the 3rd row.

Comment: @DeepSpace I made some edits above.

Comment: From what you've posted, it is very difficult to assess what is going on, especially that we don't know where the error is happening, and what is in the data.csv. Try investigate, how your variables look like in every step. or provide some likes from data.csv

Comment: @Ouss I'm feeling that may be may problem

Comment: 1     2012-08-02  13:10:00  
2     2012-08-02  13:39:00

Comment: @Ouss my example columns are above. I'm trying to figure out if I can change their formatting

Comment: The error message does not match the shown code, as that has no `line 93`. And there's a parenthesis missing.

Comment: Please provide an example value of date[0], an example value of x[0], and example value of y[0]

Comment: @Ouss date[0] = 2012-08-01
x[0] = 04:04:00
y[0] = 66.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues here that your `data.csv` have the format (that you provided in a comments)... note that you need to use `' '` (a space) as the delimiter in pandas `read_csv()` function, because the data in your `.csv` is space separated and not comma separated:

```
$ cat data.csv
2012-08-02 13:10:00 66.4
2012-08-02 13:39:00 33.4
2012-08-03 13:39:00 66.8
2012-08-03 17:39:00 39.1
```

Now lets load the csv data into pandas using `read_csv()`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',names= ['date','x','y'], sep=' ')
```

now data is a data frame containing the entries in the file data.csv. however all columns are have str() type. You have to convert the column (to parse it) to `datetime` using the pandas `to_datetime()` function:

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
```

now you can continue with the rest of the code:

```
date = data['date']
date_difference = date[3]- date[2]

print(date_difference)
```

that should give the following result:

```
Timedelta('4 days 00:00:00')
```

Note that `date_difference` is a `Timedelta` variable.

For more on dealing with dates check:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

For more on pandas.read_csv check: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

For more on pandas.to_datetime check:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: How would the date difference be 4 days?

Comment: Oh I see now. It was just an example! Thank you so much! I'm trying to combines date and x to be able to find the difference now

Comment: This work perfectly THANK YOU